# Multiple Videos In Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, colorbox

I'm trying to put multiple youtube videos in a colorbox popup such that when you open it you have the option to scroll between them, like you would with a group of pictures.

I have 3 videos, I open the colorbox with a button and thats where I'm stuck.

I'm sure its simple, I just don't know the format It requires.

Hope someone can help.

Denver

```
<a class="group2 youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rGhUnJ7SVc" ></a>
<a class="group2 youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rGhUnJ7SVc" ></a>
<a class="group2 youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rGhUnJ7SVc" ></a>

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:1000, innerHeight:600});
      $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade", width:"90%", height:"90%"});
  });
```

Comment: Some code or a fiddle would help us help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what code is needed.

Comment: The code which you have you tried before posting a question on SO ?

Comment: Thats the thing I do not know what it would be

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to insert the video embed url into href attribute instead of video url, and you can set the group in the rel attribute of links sg like this:

```
<a class="youtube" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4rGhUnJ7SVc" rel="group1">video 1</a>
<a class="youtube" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4rGhUnJ7SVc" rel="group1">video 1</a>
<a class="youtube" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4rGhUnJ7SVc" rel="group1">video 1</a>
```

After that you can make a colorbox from links this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:1000, innerHeight:600});
}
```